# How to keep track of ids of rows of tables created by clicking checkbox when they can be deleted randomly

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

```js
var m=0;
var tablemap=new Map();
var booleantable=[];
var keepingvalueofsubtable=[];
$(document).ready(function()
{  var array_items=[];


var obj=$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)");

console.log(obj[0]["id"]);
for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
   $("#"+obj[i]['id']+"form").hide();

   tablemap[i]=obj[i]['id'];
   booleantable[i]=0;
    keepingvalueofsubtable[i] = [];

}

    ;  


$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});


$('.frameopener').on('change', function(){
    {
       
           var formid=$(this).attr("id");
 
       
   
  $("#" + formid + "form").toggle();
    

}
});


 




 $('.c').click(function () {
       
 var m=$(this).attr('data-value');
 
    


    


booleantable[m]=booleantable[m]+1;

var html='<div class="div-table-row">';
             html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="zerofirst" contenteditable="true"></div>';
               html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>';
                html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="one" contenteditable="true">0</div>';
                html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="two" contenteditable="true">0</div>';
               html+=' <div class="div-table-col" id="three" >0</div>';
              
               
              html+=' <div class="div-table-col"><center><div  class="del" aria-hidden="true"  data-value="0"  ><i class="fas fa-trash delete" ></i></div></center></div>';

               html+='</center></div>';
  

$("#"+tablemap[m]+"form").append(html);
alert(html);
html="";


});



 $(document).on('click','.del',function(){


alert();

//alert($(this).attr('data-value').value());
alert($(this).attr("id"));
//const slug = str.substring(str.indexOf('-') + 1);
  
//alert(slug);

  } );
 



});
```

```css
 {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background-color:#f1f1f1;
  }
  .box
  {
   width:1270px;
   padding:20px;
   background-color:#fff;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius:5px;
   margin-top:25px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
  }

.div-table {
  display: table;         
  width: auto;         
  background-color: #eee;         
  border: 1px solid #666666;         
  border-spacing: 5px; /* cellspacing:poor IE support for  this */
}
.div-table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.div-table-col {
  float: left; /* fix for  buggy browsers */
  display: table-column;         
  width: 200px;         
  background-color: #ccc;  
}
.bttn{
width:100px;
height:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e22ff3c413.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <div class="table-responsive"><table  class="table"><tbody>
 
<tr><center> <legend>Choose your Block Items</legend><center><tr></tr><tr>
 
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="mobilisation" ></td><td>Mobilisation
  </td>
 
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="demolition" ></td><td>Demolition
  </td>
 
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="substructure" ></td><td>Sub Structure
  </td>
 
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="superstructure" ></td><td>Super Structure
  </td></tr>
 </tbody></table></div>
<form id="mobilisationform">
      <div class="div-table" id="mobilisation">
             <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col" align="center">Mobilisation</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Unit</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Quantity</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Rate</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Amount</div>
                 <div  class="div-table-col"><center><div  aria-hidden="true" class="c" id="addmobilisation" data-value="0"  ><center><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></center></div><center></div>
                
              
             </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                 <div class="div-table-col" id="zerofirst" contenteditable="true"></div>
                <div class="div-table-col" id="ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>
                  <div class="div-table-col" id="one" contenteditable="true">0</div>
                <div class="div-table-col" id="two" contenteditable="true">0</div>
                <div class="div-table-col" id="three" >0</div>
                 <div class="div-table-col"><center><div   aria-hidden="true" class="del" id="delete-0" data-value="0"  ><i class="fas fa-trash delete" ></i></div></center></div>
            </div>

      </div>
  </form>


<form id="demolitionform">
      <div class="div-table" id="demolition">
             <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col" align="center">Demolition</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Unit</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Quantity</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Rate</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Amount</div>
                 <div  class="div-table-col"><center><div  aria-hidden="true" class="c" id="adddemolition" data-value="1"  ><center><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></center></div><center></div>
                
              
             </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                 <div class="div-table-col" id="zerofirst" contenteditable="true"></div>
                <div class="div-table-col" id="ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>
                  <div class="div-table-col" id="one" contenteditable="true">0</div>
                <div class="div-table-col" id="two" contenteditable="true">0</div>
                <div class="div-table-col" id="three" >0</div>
                 <div class="div-table-col"><center><div   aria-hidden="true" class="del" id="delete-1" data-value="0"  ><i class="fas fa-trash delete" ></i></div></center></div>
            </div>

      </div>
  </form>


<form id="substructureform">
      <div class="div-table" id="substructure">
             <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col" align="center">Sub Structure</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Unit</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Quantity</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Rate</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Amount</div>
                 <div  class="div-table-col"><center><div  aria-hidden="true" class="c" id="addsubstructure" data-value="2"  ><center><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></center></div><center></div>
                
              
             </div>
            <div class="div-table-row">
                 <div class="div-table-col" id="zerofirst" contenteditable="true"></div>
                <div class="div-table-col" id="ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>
                  <div class="div-table-col" id="one" contenteditable="true">0</div>
                <div class="div-table-col" id="two" contenteditable="true">0</div>
                <div class="div-table-col" id="three" >0</div>
                 <div class="div-table-col"><center><div   aria-hidden="true" class="del" id="delete-2" data-value="0"  ><i class="fas fa-trash delete" ></i></div></center></div>
            </div>

      </div>
  </form>


<form id="superstructureform">
      <div class="div-table" id="superstructure">
             <div class="div-table-row">
                <div class="div-table-col" align="center">Super Structure</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Unit</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Quantity</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Rate</div>
                <div  class="div-table-col">Amount</div>
                 <div  class="div-table-col"><center><div  aria-hidden="true" class="c" id="addsuperstructure" data-value="3"  ><center><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></center></div><center></div>
```

**Create a sub table for a list of check items.**

I have a list of checkbox. When you click the checkbox, a table made with a div gets displayed. The problem with this, is that the table that I assign ids to these rows of this table as `<tablename>+<tableid>+<subtableid>.` There is a column for deleting the rows of sub table. As I click delete from the middle of the table, the rows get deleted. What is the easiest way to keep track of undeleted rows? I need to pass all the rows to next php page as a post. I also need to compute the amount by multiplying quantity and rate and find total amount. What is the easiest way to do this?

Here is what I'be tried:

php:

```
foreach( $checkboxitemsafterstripper as $key => $item ){


    echo '
    <form id="'.$item.'form">
          <div class="div-table" id="'.$item.'">
                 ....'
 <div  class="div-table-col"><center><div  aria-hidden="true" class="c" id="add'.$item.'" data-value="'.$key.'"  ><center><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></center></div><center></div>
                <div   aria-hidden="true" class="del" id="delete-'.$key.'" data-value="0"  ><i class="fas fa-trash delete" ></i></div></center>
```

jquery:

```
var obj=$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)");

console.log(obj[0]["id"]);
for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
   $("#"+obj[i]['id']+"form").hide();

   tablemap[i]=obj[i]['id'];
   booleantable[i]=0;
    keepingvalueofsubtable[i] = [];

}
$('.c').click(function () {
       
 var m=$(this).attr('data-value');

booleantable[m]=booleantable[m]+1;

var html='<div class="div-table-row">';
             html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="zerofirst" contenteditable="true"></div>';
               html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>';
                html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="one" contenteditable="true">0</div>';
                html+='<div class="div-table-col" id="two" contenteditable="true">0</div>';
               html+=' <div class="div-table-col" id="three" >0</div>';
              // html+='<div class="div-table-col"><div class="del" aria-hidden="true"  id="delete-'+m+'-'+booleantable[m]+'" data-value="'+booleantable[m]+'"  ><center><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></center></div></div>';
               
              html+=' <div class="div-table-col"><center><div  class="del" aria-hidden="true"  data-value="0"  ><i id="'+tablemap[m]+'-'+m+'-'+booleantable[m]+'"class="fas fa-trash delete" ></i></div></center></div>';

               html+='</center></div>';
  

$("#"+tablemap[m]+"form").append(html);
alert(html);
html="";


});
```

How to implement delete part:

```
$(document).on('click','.del',function(event){

console.log(event.target.id);


  } );
 



});
    ';
    }
```

jquery part:

[image]

My code works fine in chrome but not in Firefox. Why is it like that?

Here is the full code:

https://pastebin.com/4TuRiVA1

I have included a jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ehd94t8k/1/

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Far too much irrelevant code provided. Just provide enough html and js( without php) to make this a minimal example of the specific problem at hand

Comment: @charlietfl Is it ok now

Comment: @El_Vanja sorry.Is it ok now

Comment: @somanraj - not really better - all you need to do is run your app, right click on the page and hit view Source. Copy that and bring it.

Comment: No... is not raw html that we can work with. None of that php is relevant to the client side problem you are asking about. Php only runs on server. You can also copy raw html from browser dev tools elements inspector

Comment: @charlietfl https://paste.debian.net/1176809/

Comment: Great but the minimal code needs to be in the question, not aa full page of code in a pastebin

Comment: @charlietfl Ok I shall try to do that..

Comment: If you click on `<>` in question editor can make a runnable snippet right here in the page. Don't need to worry about a lot of css... just enough to render the basic  table/buttons etc

Comment: @charlietfl I have included jsfiddle.

Comment: The jsfiddle looks very similar to the image in your SO post.  What's the next step?  Keeping track of deleted rows?  Making a stackoverflow snippet?

Comment: Your table which is created on click of checkboxes has add button ? so more rows can be added ? which id you need to tracks ? please elaborate .

Comment: @Swathi I need to select all the values which are being dynamically created using $(".c").click.

Comment: can you use ajax here ? sending all tables datas using json & ajax ?

Comment: @Swati yes definitely.But i am not familiar with that.Can you give me some examples on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `divs` are created dynamically you need to bind it with static elements i.e : any div , body ,document etc. Then , whenever user `input` on `one` or `two` divs get the required value using `$(this).text()` and other value using `.closest()` and `find()` and add required value to `.three` .

Next, whenever `delete` button is clicked simply use  `$(this).closest(".div-table-row").remove()` to remove entire div.

Lastly, for sending these values to backend you can create *JSON Array* by iterating through form and getting required values and pushing them to main array.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var m = 0;
var tablemap = new Map();
var booleantable = [];
var keepingvalueofsubtable = [];
//when one is input
$(document).on('input', '.one', function() {
  //get text using this and other input using closest
  var value = parseFloat($(this).text()) * parseFloat($(this).closest(".div-table-row").find(".two").text());
  if (isNaN(value))
    value = 0;
  $(this).closest(".div-table-row").find(".three").text(value);
});
$(document).on('input', '.two', function() {
  var valuetwo = parseFloat($(this).text()) * parseFloat($(this).closest(".div-table-row").find(".one").text());
  if (isNaN(valuetwo))
    valuetwo = 0;
  $(this).closest(".div-table-row").find(".three").text(valuetwo);


});
var array_items = [];
var obj = $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)");

for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
  $("#" + obj[i]['id'] + "form").hide();

  tablemap[i] = obj[i]['id'];
  booleantable[i] = 0;
  keepingvalueofsubtable[i] = [];

}

$('.frameopener').on('change', function() {
  {
    var formid = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#" + formid + "form").toggle();
  }
});


$('.c').click(function() {

  var m = $(this).attr('data-value');
  booleantable[m] = booleantable[m] + 1;
  //added class
  var html = '<div class="div-table-row">';
  html += '<div class="div-table-col zerofirst " contenteditable="true"></div>';
  html += '<div class="div-table-col ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>';
  html += '<div class="div-table-col one"  contenteditable="true">0</div>';
  html += '<div class="div-table-col two"  contenteditable="true">0</div>';
  html += ' <div class="div-table-col three"  >0</div>';
  html += ' <div class="div-table-col"><center><div  class="del" aria-hidden="true"  data-value="0"  ><i class="fas fa-trash delete" >delete</i></div></center></div>';

  html += '</center></div>';


  $("#" + tablemap[m] + "form").append(html);
  alert(html);
  html = "";


});


$(document).on('click', '.del', function() {
  $(this).closest(".div-table-row").remove() //remove rows
});


$("button.submit").click(function() {
  var main_array = new Array()
  //form which is visible
  $("form:visible").each(function() {
    //get id
    var table_of = $(this).attr('id');
    var main_inside = {} //create obj
    main_inside[table_of] = new Array();
    //loop through rows not first
    $(this).find(".div-table-row:not(:first)").each(function() {
      var inputs = {}; //creat obj
      //get values
      inputs["zeroone"] = $(this).find(".div-table-col:eq(0)").text();
      inputs["zerotwo"] = $(this).find(".div-table-col:eq(1)").text();
      inputs["one"] = $(this).find(".div-table-col:eq(2)").text();
      inputs["two"] = $(this).find(".div-table-col:eq(3)").text();
      inputs["three"] = $(this).find(".div-table-col:eq(4)").text();
      main_inside[table_of].push(inputs); //push in main_inside 


    })
    main_array.push(main_inside) //finally push in main array


  })
  console.log(main_array)
  //your json ..stringfy  & ajax request

})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.box {
  width: 1270px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div-table {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  /* cellspacing:poor IE support for  this */
}

.div-table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.div-table-col {
  float: left;
  /* fix for  buggy browsers */
  display: table-column;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bttn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <center>
        <legend>Choose your Block Items</legend>
      </center>

      <tr>

        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="mobilisation"></td>
        <td>Mobilisation
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="frameopener" id="demolition"></td>
        <td>Demolition
        </td>


      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<form id="mobilisationform">
  <div class="div-table" id="mobilisation">
    <div class="div-table-row">
      <div class="div-table-col" align="center">Mobilisation</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">Unit</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">Quantity</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">Rate</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">Amount</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">
        <center>
          <div aria-hidden="true" class="c" id="addmobilisation" data-value="0">
            <center><i class="fas fa-plus">add</i></center>
          </div>
        </center>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="div-table-row">
    <!--added class-->
      <div class="div-table-col zerofirst" contenteditable="true"></div>
      <div class="div-table-col ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>
      <div class="div-table-col one" contenteditable="true">0</div>
      <div class="div-table-col two" contenteditable="true">0</div>
      <div class="div-table-col three" class="three">0</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">
        <center>
          <div aria-hidden="true" class="del" id="delete-0" data-value="0"><i class="fas fa-trash delete">delete</i></div>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>


<form id="demolitionform">
  <div class="div-table" id="demolition">
    <div class="div-table-row">
      <div class="div-table-col" align="center">Demolition</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">Unit</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">Quantity</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">Rate</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">Amount</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">
        <center>
          <div aria-hidden="true" class="c" id="adddemolition" data-value="1">
            <center><i class="fas fa-plus">add</i></center>
          </div>
        </center>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="div-table-row">
      <div class="div-table-col zerofirst" contenteditable="true"></div>
      <div class="div-table-col ZeroSecond" contenteditable="true"></div>
      <div class="div-table-col one" contenteditable="true">0</div>
      <div class="div-table-col two" contenteditable="true">0</div>
      <div class="div-table-col three">0</div>
      <div class="div-table-col">
        <center>
          <div aria-hidden="true" class="del" id="delete-1" data-value="0"><i class="fas fa-trash delete">delete</i></div>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>


<button class="submit" type="submit">Submit All</button>
<out></out>
```